# Invalidate token issue with laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I use JWTAuth Token. I want to invalidate a token when an admin deactivate the user from admin panel. the problem is when user is login from app side if admin deactivate the current login user the token of that specific user is not invalidate . After deactivating from backend the user is login from app side. Here is my code Please help Thank you

```
public function logout()
{
    $token = JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());

    return response()->json(['message'=>  $token]);
}
```

Comment: Try this JWTAuth::invalidate('user token to be deactivated');

Comment: I also do this but not working

Comment: Okay, so you want the user to logout if the user token is deactivate via admin area? am i correct?

Comment: yes i want this exactly

Comment: Even the token is being deactivated still the user can stay login becauase session already in place to the app. Now for that to work is that you need to touch the user table and middleware, if the user is deactivated then middleware will know and trigger  the user to trigger logout.

Comment: How i would do this ?

Comment: the invalidate fucntion is also not working ?

Comment: Create add column in users.status you can add the status as active or deactivated when the admin do the action and when the app reloaded the app, middleware will check the users.status if active or deactiveted. 

If status is deactivated then the middleware will trigger the app user to logout page.

This mean your user need to do any activity inside app so that the logout action will triggered

Comment: I wrote above invalidate function not worked ?

Comment: I also add the key in user table that changes to 0 or 1 After check what can i do in logout function i would be invalid the as i mention my code above if invalidate function is not worked than what can i do ?

Comment: Any one help me in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

By changing the CACHE_DRIVER from array to redis/memcached is worked for me.

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
```

I hope this helps someone.